# Recursive access to elements in list of lists in R

Tags: r, list, nested-lists

I'm using the Annotation package of R to get GO terms related to certain genes. Using getGOParents(term) function the result is:

```
> x = getGOParents("GO:0035556")

$`GO:0035556`
$`GO:0035556`$Ontology
[1] "BP"

$`GO:0035556`$Parents
    is_a 
"GO:0007165"
```

The structure of the list is:

```
dput(x)
structure(list(`GO:0035556` = structure(list(Ontology = "BP", 
Parents = structure("GO:0007165", .Names = "is_a")), .Names = c("Ontology", 
"Parents"))), .Names = "GO:0035556")
```

I need to access the "last" term of the list, I did it in a really silly way:

```
y=x[1]
z=y[[1]]
w=z[[2]]
s=w[[1]]
```

Is there a way to programmatically access it?

Comment: Could you please add a `dput` of your list as it is hard to see its structure from what you pasted. And please also describe the value you want to get in the end...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this function for it:

```
getParent <- function(x){
    parent = NA
    if(exists(x,revmap(GOBPCHILDREN))){
        parents = get(x,revmap(GOBPCHILDREN))
        parent = tail(parents, n=1)
    }
    if(!is.na(parent)){
        return(parent)
    }
    return(NA)
}
```

But I didn't want the highest parents, because this one is always the same. So I changed the function to:

```
getParent <- function(x){
    parent = NA
    if(exists(x,revmap(GOBPCHILDREN))){
        parents = get(x,revmap(GOBPCHILDREN))
        parent = tail(parents, n=4)[1] ##change the 4 to which level you want
    }
    if(!is.na(parent)){
        return(parent)
    }
    return(NA)
}
```

A nice visualisation tool for the GO terms is GOrilla: http://cbl-gorilla.cs.technion.ac.il/

I hope u can do something with this information

Comment: I just copied yout function and tried with x=GO:0004726, and it gives me NA while it has several ancestors (http://amigo.geneontology.org/cgi-bin/amigo/term_details?term=GO:0004726)

Comment: @Lazza87 This is only of the BP (Biological Process) Your GO ID contains a MF (Molecular Function), so change the GOBPCHILDREN into GOMFCHILDREN.

Comment: Now it seems to work, but is the parameter n the number of ancestors that the method should return? Because using n=4 it returns only the "first" parent

Comment: @Lazza87 n=4 returns a parent, which has still 3 parents, so you don't select the top level, which is always the type you are using (BP,CC or MF). When you want a lower child, you can use the n=<levels lower than parent>. If you want all parents, you have to remove the [1].

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rapply` which is a recursive version of lapply. Here I apply the identity function on the terminal nodes of your list.

```
 rapply(x,f=I)
GO:0035556.Ontology GO:0035556.Parents.is_a 
               "BP"            "GO:0007165"
```

Or to access one by one

```
rapply(x,f=I)[2] 
GO:0035556.Parents.is_a 
       "GO:0007165"
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you could have condensed your method to

```
x[[1]][[2]][[1]]
```

One thing you could do is remove the list structure by using `unlist`

```
unlist(x)
#GO:0035556.Ontology GO:0035556.Parents.is_a 
#               "BP"            "GO:0007165"
```

and you can access those individually through indexing

```
> unlist(x)[1]
GO:0035556.Ontology 
               "BP" 
> unlist(x)[2]
GO:0035556.Parents.is_a 
           "GO:0007165"
```